# Encontrar el camino que de la menor suma en un arreglo de 3x3 C#

Tags: c#, array-bidimensional

Se tiene una matriz de 3 x 3 que contiene números del 1 al 9, pero esta matriz esta simulada usando una matriz unidimensional. Así, por ejemplo, esta matriz:

```
1 2 9
2 5 3
5 1 5
```

Se representaría como (1,2,9,2,5,3,5,1,5). El objetivo es identificar **el camino que de la menor suma al recorrer el arreglo** bi-dimencional de izquierda a derecha de **forma adyacente**.

Hasta el momentos tengo este código:

```
    int [][] array=new int[3][]
{
    new int[3] {1,2,9},
    new int[3] {2,5,3},
    new int[3] {5,1,5}
};
    int posIni=0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.Length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i][0]<array[posIni][0])
        {
            posIni=i;
        }
    }
    
    int posInis=0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.Length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i][1]<array[posInis][1])
        {
            posInis=i;
        }
      
    }

    int posInit=0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.Length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i][2]<array[posInit][2])
        {
            posInit=i;
        }
    }
  Console.Write(array[posIni][0]);
  Console.Write(array[posInis][1]);
  Console.Write(array[posInit][2]);
```

Pero me imprime esto (no está bien ya que debe ser de forma adyacente):

- 113

Y la salida esperada del programa es:

- 1 2 3

Espero me ayuden pronto, muchas gracias.

Comment: no lei toda tu pregunta.. pero para empezar, la salida esperada no seria 1 1 3???

Comment: Es interesante. Los caminos en la matriz deben ser entre elementos adyacentes?

Comment: Exacto, si debe ser entre caminos adyacentes

Comment: Entonces estaba bien el 1 2 3... podrias aclarar todas esas cosas en la pregunta? de paso, que trataste de hacer con tu codigo? y todo se arregla, si en lugar de dentro del for, sacas los Console.Write (los 3) fuera de los for.. vas a ver que lindo queda...

Comment: Listo ya lo organice un poco más, y con el código básicamente lo que trato de hacer es imprimir el menor de cada columna, pero como debe ser de forma adyacente me falla el valor del medio (1,1,3) ya que la forma correcta es (1,2,3)